# How do I fix issues with using both javascript in an external file and javascript within html

Tags: javascript, html, onload

I am building a TV application.

1. it uses keypress navigation
2. the application should display performance details as well because there won't be access to developer tools

This is my code to get the performance details

```
<script>
  window.onload = function () {
    if ("timing" in window.performance) {
      document.getElementById("total_download_time").innerHTML = "<span class='color-class'>Page download time :</span> " + "<span class='color-class'>" + (window.performance.timing.responseEnd - window.performance.timing.navigationStart) + " <span class='color-class'>ms</span>";
      document.getElementById("total_render_time").innerHTML = "<span class='color-class'>Page rendering time :</span> " + "<span class='color-class'>" + (window.performance.timing.loadEventStart - window.performance.timing.domLoading) + "</span>" + "<span class='color-class'> ms</san>";
      document.getElementById("latency").innerHTML = "<span class='color-class'>Latency :</span> " + "<span class='color-class'>" + (window.performance.timing.responseStart - window.performance.timing.fetchStart) + "</span>" + "<span class='color-class'> ms</san>";
      document.getElementById("dom_lookup_time").innerHTML = "<span class='color-class'>Dom Lookup Time :</span> " + "<span class='color-class'>" + (window.performance.timing.domainLookupEnd - window.performance.timing.domainLookupStart) + "</span>" + "<span class='color-class'> ms</san>";
      document.getElementById("server_connect_time").innerHTML = "<span class='color-class'>Server Connect time :</span> " + "<span class='color-class'>" + (window.performance.timing.connectEnd - window.performance.timing.connectStart) + "</span>" + "<span class='color-class'> ms</san>";
      document.getElementById("page_load_time").innerHTML = "<span class='color-class'>Page Load time :</span> " + "<span class='color-class'>" + (window.performance.timing.loadEventStart - window.performance.timing.navigationStart) + "</span>" + "<span class='color-class'> ms</san>";
      document.getElementById("redirection_time").innerHTML = "<span class='color-class'>Redirection time :</span> " + "<span class='color-class'>" + (window.performance.timing.redirectEnd - window.performance.timing.redirectStart) + "</span>" + "<span class='color-class'> ms</san>";
      document.getElementById("dom_content_load_time").innerHTML = "<span class='color-class'>Dom Content Load time :</span> " + "<span class='color-class'>" + (window.performance.timing.domContentLoadedEventEnd - window.performance.timing.navigationStart) + "</span>" + "<span class='color-class'> ms</san>";
    }
    else {
      document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "Page Timing API not supported";
    }
  }
</script>
```

I have written this in the HTML file itself

However, I have another  .js file which has the code required for keypress navigation

key_navigation.js

```
function init() {
  document.addEventListener("keydown", function (e) {
    if (eventExec(e.keyCode))
      e.preventDefault();
  }, false);
  document.addEventListener("keydown", function (e) {
    if (handleKeyCode(e.keyCode))
      e.preventDefault();
  }, false);

  // set appMngr to the application/oipfApplicationManager object
  var appMgr = document.getElementById("oipfID");
  if (typeof (appMgr.getOwnerApplication) != "undefined") {
    // create the application
    int_app = appMgr.getOwnerApplication(document);
    //setting remote control buttons
    int_keyset = int_app.privateData.keyset;
    int_ksVisible = 0x23F;
    int_app.show();
    int_keyset.setValue(int_ksVisible);
  }
}
```

The keypress works fine when the script for performance is not added.
Once I add the performance script , the keypress navigation doesnt work.
How can I fix this?

Comment: What exactly does "doesn't work" mean? Are errors reported? Does *anything* happen?

Comment: there is no error message in the console but pressing down key doesn't go to the next menu selection

Comment: I was able to navigate through menu and press enter which goes to the next page before adding the script to display performance details

Comment: I wonder if whatever calls `init` in your keypress file uses window.onload. What happens if you use `window.addEventListener("load", function() ...)` instead?

Comment: Thank you so much. It works @AustinMullins

Comment: Lucky guess, LOL